# Testcafe: Getting error: Cannot implicitly resolve the test run

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm writing the script in testcafe to parse the response and verify, that response contains required text, nut getting an error: **Cannot implicitly resolve the test run in the context of which the test controller action should be executed. Use test function's 't' argument instead.**

```
test ('Control server info', async () => {

    await t
      .click(infoserver.serverinfoButton)
      .click(infoserver.getInfoButton)

    await infoserver.resultText.value.then( async (res) => {
        const infoParse = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(infoParse);

    await t
    .expect(infoParse.username).contains('Google:cloudtester12345@gmail.com');

    });
});
```

Comment: In my short experience with Testcafe I found this error often triggers because of some other error, either in the test code it self or the application being tested.

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
test ('Control server info', async t => {

//test code
});
```

Comment: Seems `t` could only be used in `async t` block, but I wonder what does the error message mean?